# Redirect www to non-www url

Tags: nginx, next.js, amazon-ec2, next.js13

I have deployed my NextJs-app on AWS ec2 instance using nginx. I have got ssl from letsencrypt.

Here is the nginx config for the app [Nginx Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/816NK.png):-

The site is working correctly and the http traffic is redirected to https but www url is not being redirected to non-www.

I want to redirect https://www.skytrust.ca to https://skytrust.ca.

How can I achieve this ?